# PHP Class get Global Variable

Tags: php, twitter

I am using https://github.com/seaofclouds/tweet

I want to pass `index.php?consumer_key=xxx`.
After passing this I want to get in the PHP class but i am getting error.

Here is the Code below. Full Code: http://pastebin.com/gCzxrhu4

```
//$consumer_key = $_GET['consumer_key'];

class ezTweet {
   private $consumer_key = $consumer_key; // getting error
   private $consumer_key = 'xxxxx'; // working
   private $consumer_secret = 'xxxx';

//other things

}
```

Please Help.

Comment: why both the varibles has the same name?

Comment: A class is a stand-alone, re-usable unit of code. It therefore, should not, under _any_ circumstances, rely on **GLOBAL** variables to initialize its properties or do its job. If you need a class to have access to a value, _pass that value to the class_.

Comment: I just add them to test and explain here.

Comment: Can someone fix my code initialize all variables: http://pastebin.com/gCzxrhu4

Comment: @MoinAKbar: This site is not a free debugger service, but I might be willing to refactor/fix the problem, but that all depends on how much you're willing to pay...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A class is a stand-alone, re-usable and portable unit of code.
Therefore, it should never, ever, under *any* circumstances, rely on ***GLOBAL*** variables to initialize its properties or do its job.

If you need a class to have access to a value, pass that value to the class, either through the constructor or a setter method:

```
class EzTweet
{//class names start with UpperCase, and the { goes on the next line
    private $consumer_key = null;//initialize to default, null
    public function __construct($cKey = null)
    {//pass value here, but default to null -> optional
        $this->consumer_key = $cKey;//set value
    }
    public function setConsumerKey($cKey)
    {
        $this->consumer_key = $cKey;//set value later on through setter
        return $this;
    }
}

//use:
$ezTwitter = new EzTwitter();
if (isset($_GET['consumer_key']))
    $ezTwitter->SetConsumerKey($_GET['consumer_key']);//set value
```

That's what I'd do, anyways. BTW: please check, and try to stick to, the [coding standards](http://www.php-fig.org).

---

Update:
It turns out you already have a constructor. Fine, just change it a bit to:

```
public function __construct($cKey = null)//add argument
{
    $this->consumer_key = $cKey;//add this
    // Initialize paths and etc.
    $this->pathify($this->cache_dir);
    $this->pathify($this->lib);
    $this->message = '';
    // Set server-side debug params
    if ($this->debug === true)
      error_reporting(-1);
    else
      error_reporting(0);
}
```

Comment: @MoinAkbar: Refactoring and debugging are your job. If you want to write code, you'll have to accept and get used to the fact that debugging is part of the job. However, looking at the error message you posted in another comment: just add `$cKey = null` to your **existing constructor** argument list (empty atm), and add the `$this->consumer_key = $cKey;` line to the method body. DO NOT ADD A SECOND CONSTRUCTOR

Answer (score 0):

You can't set the property class value with a $variable, in this case you need before construct your class.

```
class ezTweet 
{
    private $consumer_key = '';

    private $consumer_secret = 'xxxx';

    public function __construct($consumer_key)
    {
        if (!is_string($consumer_key) || !strlen(trim($consumer_key))) {
            throw new \InvalidArgumentException('"consumer_key" cannot be empty!');
        }
        $this->consumer_key = $consumer_key;
    }

    public function getConsumerKey()
    {
        return $this->consumer_key;
    }
}

$consumer_key = (isset($_GET['consumer_key']) ? $_GET['consumer_key'] : null);

try {
    $ezTweet = new ezTweet($consumer_key);
    // [...]
}
catch (\InvalidArgumentException $InvalidArgumentException) {
    echo $InvalidArgumentException->getMessage();
}
```

Comment: @Elias Van Ootegem  "setConsumerKey" is a vulnerability, anyone with the instance can change the "consumer_key"

Comment: Yes, but you can do some data validation in a setter. Besides, anyone can create an instance of this clsas either way, and pass any value to the constructor. What's to stop me from just adding a line to your snippet `$ezTweet = new ezTweet('invalidKey');`? Same thing, only if I have 2 _valid_ keys, I have to create 2 instances with your code, a setter allows me to re-use a single instance, and (again), perform some validation on the values that are being site (example: `setEmail` calls `filter_var($argument, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)`).

Comment: Besides, `private` doesn't mean it is invulnerable: try `var_dump((array) $objWithPrivate);` or what if I did some `str_replace`/`preg_replace` trickery on `serialize($instance)` and then tried `$instance = unserialize($alteredString);`? And those are just the hard parts. What about magic getters and setters? I'm 100% against these magic methods, but they are often implemented, effectively exposing all private properties... a setter is not exactly a big security risk